# How to mount a Lumix G7 with Panasonic H-FS 1442A lens to 1.25" telescope

Tags: astrophotography, panasonic-lumix, amateur

I have a Lumix G7 with a Panasonic H-FS 1442A and I want to mount it to a telescope with a 1.25" eyepiece size.

I know I can get a Micro Four Thirds adapter and mount it straight to the telescope, but that means the lens is not involved.

**Is there any way to mount it including the lens?**

This would allow me to still have autofocus and be able to zoom a bit too.

The lens has a 46mm filter inner thread, and some kind of outer attachment mount that I haven't been able to identify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the lens is not worth it

- Your auto-focus won't work too well on a night sky (for focus, nothing beats manual focus on a zoomed live-view)
- You are very likely to create optical aberrations
- You are going to suspend your lens+camera to the filter thread of the lens, which isn't meant to carry that kind of weight.